# ¿Por qué mi me lanza error en la conexión a la BD de mi app en adroid?

Tags: java, android

Tengo una app que hace unas consultas simples a una BD de Sql Server. En el emulador funciona bien pero cuando generé la apk me lanza un error en la conexion a la BD. Imagino que el error irá por mis datos para la conexión pero como repito en el emulador todo funciona bien.

Este es el codigo de mi clase conexion:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy politica  = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(politica);
    Connection conn = null;
    String ConnUrl = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        ConnUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + ip + ":1433/" + dbc + ";instance=" + instance + ";user=" + un + ";password=" + password + ";";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnUrl);
    }
    catch (SQLException se) {
        Log.e("ERROR", se.getMessage());
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException cne) {
        Log.e("ERROR", cne.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: ¿Y qué error te lanza?

Comment: Que error se muestra en el LogCat, agrega esta informaciòn cuando crees preguntas, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: gracias y lo siento es que soy nuevo aquí